# Refresh ScrollView In Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

does someone know how to detect if the UI Component "ScrollView" has been pulled up?.
This is planned to be like, when you refresh the feed in youtube or facebook, with the swipe up gesture.
It should detect the gesture and then, called a method that I have : refresh();
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ScrollRect:**

You can subscribe to ScrollRect's `onValueChanged` event and it will be called when there are changes on the `ScrollRect`.

```
public ScrollRect scrollRect;

void OnEnable()
{
    scrollRect.onValueChanged.AddListener(ScrollChanged);
}

void OnDisable()
{
    scrollRect.onValueChanged.RemoveAllListeners();
}

void ScrollChanged(Vector2 pos)
{
    Debug.Log("Scroll changed pos to: " + pos);
}
```

or you can implement the `IScrollHandler` interface and use the `OnScroll` function. The script will have to be attached to the GameObject that has the `ScrollRect` component for it to work.

```
public class ScrollDetector : MonoBehaviour, IScrollHandler
{
    public void OnScroll(PointerEventData eventData)
    {

    }
}
```

---

**Scrollbar:**

If using `Scrollbar`, then the callback function you register with the `onValueChanged` event should use `float` instead `vector2` as param.

```
void ScrollChanged(float val)
{

}
```

or implement the `IMoveHandler` interface and use the `OnMove` function

```
public class ScrollDetector : MonoBehaviour, IMoveHandler
{
    public void OnMove(AxisEventData eventData)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I noticed [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1544176/scrollviewscrollrect-scrolling-refresh-event.html) someone registered `AddListener(OnScrollRectChange)` but you registered `AddListener(ScrollChanged)`. What is the difference?